# How to use 'a' link for external link on react but also passing in a prop using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, hyperlink

How to use 'a' link for external link on react but also passing in a prop using react?

```
<a
                  target={"_blank"}
                  href={`https://www.google.com/maps/dir//${this.props.business.lat},${this.props.business.lng}`}
                >
                  Get Directions
                </a>
```

Im trying to pass in business.lat and business.lng. but its still linking to local host. how do i set it so it goes to just google maps?

Comment: The double slash looks weird. Apart from that, this should work. Can you show the whole render method? What is the value of `this.props` that you are passing, what DOM element is rendered, and where does the link actually point to (that you don't want)?

Comment: Hi, right now its going to http://localhost:3000/www.google.com/maps/dir//40.76068220846901,-73.83302248127391. i want to remove the local host: 3000. if you just remove the local host its just directing to the google direction page with position set on map.

Comment: That looks like you either forgot the `https://` in your string, or something in your (dev) build chain is messing with links. This does not normally happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy pasted that to my react project and that works as expected. When I removed "https://" from the link it goes to localhost. Are you sure you didn't miss that in your project?

Comment: Thanks! i had that originally like in the original post. tried it without when i made comment. works!